# Reverse Proxy for Apache Kafka? Solution for many consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, websocket, reverse-proxy, gateway

I've being tinkering with a possible architecture for a location based mobile application. The mobile application provides its geolocation, the backend will use multiple 3rd party APIs to fetch data related to this location and return it back to the mobile app as consumer of its topic.

```
App -> Produces Geolocation -> 
        Backend Consumes and Fetches Data -> App consumes data from backend.
```

However, the backend will only fetch from the 3rd party apis if the location data doesn't exist already. Since the location data is common for users in that particular geolocation and is also to avoid any 3rd party API requests as much as possible.

In this case, the mobile app(s) are the consumers of the location data, which isn't ideal since it would required large partitions and wouldn't scale very well.

So I believe I would need some kind of reverse proxy, or gateway in front of Kafka to handle all requests, preferably over Websockets.

Below is a high level overview of what I was thinking.

[image]

What is the best solution to avoid the mobile app being a consumer and reduce the number of partitions/consumer groups?

Comment: This sounds like a CQRS problem, not just a proxy... _broken down by location_ - This sounds like it'll be a lot of topics to consume on (one topic per "location"?) The _list of locations_ could be a KTable, though. Also, this "proxy" would need to have a unique consumer group for every device for that to reasonably work... Why not write the data from Kafka to a database, indexed based on a geolocation, then you can poll data from the database via an API, rather than need a constant connection with a websocket to the server (which will drain the battery)

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, thanks for the advice! Yeah, it will be a lot of topics to consume, or like you said use a KTable, but I haven't seen how I would categorise the list yet, since this will be globally. I've being reading up on CQRS and is likely what I'm trying to do here. I've decided to store the data from Kafka to a redis store, which the app will read from. I will still need some reverse proxy to handle producing the data to kafka correct?

Comment: For producing data, it's all done from the backend. You'll need an API to accept external HTTP requests, which can be processed and sent to Kafka, sure. That's not what I personally consider a proxy, such as nginx, though. As for categorization, I don't know what data you have, but `groupByKey` method would probably get used somehow